# CSS -- Expanding window causes weird horizontal scroll issue

Tags: html, css, animate.css

Loading the page http://development.items-landingpage.divshot.io/ with a viewport less than 1024px then expanding to greater than 1024px causing the body to horizontally scrollable in firefox 36.0.1, Chrome 41.0.2272.89 (64-bit), and safari 8.0.4. It is weirdly not an issue if the page loads first at > 1024px then shrinking and again expanding the page.

I have narrowed this down to transform animation on the `.right` element as switching the class from `right animated fadeInUp` to `right animated fadeIn` before expanding the screen makes the issue go away. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't replicate issue in Chrome 41.0.2272.89 or Firefox 36.0.1 on Windows

Comment: Did you try refreshing the window with it shrunken then expanding it to greater than 1024px?

Comment: Yes. You are saying that a horizontal scroll bar appears? Not seeing that happen.

Comment: Yes, I'm not on windows though, instead OSX. It is possible that it isn't duplicatable in windows, though it would surprise me to be consistent across browsers only on OSX. Just tried duplicating the bug on browserstack and failed in both Windows 7 and OSX Yosemite (which I am running). I was able to have a co-worker duplicate it on their OSX machine as well.